# How do I express a boolean expression comprised of AND, OR and NOT using only AND and NOT?

Tags: boolean-logic, discrete-mathematics, circuit, hdl

Say I have the following boolean expression:

```
(A^B^C) v (~A^~C)
```

How could I express that using only AND (^) and NOT (~)? I don't want the answer, just how I would go about doing it.

Comment: Google deMorgan's Law (and, possibly, "functional completeness")? And what does this have to do with assembly?

Comment: It's the beginning part of an Assembly course online.

Comment: With DeMorgan's Law, I could apply ~~ to both, right? Is that what I should be doing? I tried that and it came out awfully long.

Comment: `(A v B) == ~(~A ^ ~B)` is the transformation you're looking for.

Comment: You can make use of De Morgan's laws as shown here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this question is showing up as unanswered, I'll echo the others and say that De Morgan's law `(A v B) == ~(~A ^ ~B)` will work.